# java declarition versus initialization

Tags: java, class, oop

I am familiar with programming, but I am learning Java. Why is it ok in Java to say

```
A test = new B()
```

Where A would be a different class from B (obviously). I understand that the `new B()` portion is just calling the initializer method for the B class. What confuses me is why would you WANT to do that? Is the `A test` creating the object in computers memory, with the initialization of A?

This question has nothing to do with interfaces. Why this is marked as a duplicate I have no idea...

Comment: The reason for `A` being different from `B` is explained in this question: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas there's more to this question than that. For example, they're asking whether `A test` is what creates the object, which isn't answered under that question.

Comment: Honestly this is why I dont like stack overflow. This guy Andreas did not read my question, but for some reason has the power to mark my question as a duplicate. Honestly, I just think that users have way too much power...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `A test` part is declaring that you have a variable called `test` and its type is `A`.
2. The `=` part means you're setting `test` on the left to what's on the right.
3. The `new B()` part means to create a new object of type `B` in memory.

So the only part that's creating an object in memory is part 3, `new B()`. To see this more clearly, you can also do something like this:

```java
A test = existingObject;
```

In this case, there is no new object created. `test` is assigned an object that already exists in memory, thus it's the `new B()` in your example that creates the object.

---

As far as assigning an object of a different type to a variable, the object **has to be** a subclass (or implementation) of the variable's type. So, if `B` is a subclass (or implementation) of `A`, then `A test = new B();` will work fine.

When using the variable `test`, only the methods defined for class (or interface) `A` will work for you. You'd have to reassign it to a variable of type `B` to gain access to `B`'s peculiar methods.

Comment: So what is it called when you create a different object from what you are declaring the type as? I was trying to find out more information about this online, but I was having a hard time expressing it in a way that the search engine could find me decent results. I would like to research this more. Also... does declaring the type define the methods that an object gets/what it can inherit? Once again I have a large amount of questions on this, so some references to further reading for this topic would be appreciated!

Comment: It's just called standard object creation. There's nothing special going on with the object creation itself. The assignment, however, is called *polymorphic assignment*. I've added a bit on how it works.

Comment: I know we arnt supposed to thank people... but seriously thank you! I was stuck on this for an two hours.